# Showing that a linear operator on $\mathbf{R}^3$ whose image is a plane must have a line as its kernel

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

So I'm not sure about how to approach this one:

> Let $\ T:\mathbf{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbf{R}^3$ be a linear operator such that the image of $T$ is a plane in $\ \mathbf{R}^3 \ $ which passes through the origin. Prove that the kernel of $T$ is a straight line which passes through the origin.

I know the equation of a plane passing through the origin is $\ Ax+By+Cz=0$, but I don't really know where to begin.

Comment: Have you covered the rank-nullity theorem?

Comment: Yes we have. 
Can I say that the if the Kernel is a plane, then the rank is 2 or something like that?

Comment: What's the dimension of the image of $T$ in this case? What does rank-nullity then tell you about the dimension of the kernel?

Comment: I'd say the dimension if the image is 2, since from the form Ax+By+Cz=0 I can put one variable in terms of the other 2. Then the dimension of the kernel would be 1.

Comment: Correct. I dare guess a part of this exercise is that you are supposed to become familiarized with the dimension of subspaces of $\Bbb{R}^3$ - a plane is a 2-dimensional thingy, a line is a 1-dimensional thingy. And in the converse direction: a 1-dimensional subspace of $\Bbb{R}^3$ is a line through the origin et cetera.

Comment: Oh, that is probably the case, since we had not worked with subespaces as planes or lines before.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

A more geometric argument, instead of using the rank-nullity theorem ...

Let $\mathbf{N}$ be a unit vector normal to the plane, and let $\mathbf{U}$ and $\mathbf{V}$ be orthogonal unit vectors parallel to the plane. Then $\{\mathbf{U}, \mathbf{V}, \mathbf{N}\}$ is an orthonormal basis for  $\mathbb{R}^3$, and the mapping $T$ can be written
$$
T(x\mathbf{U}+y\mathbf{V}+z\mathbf{N}) = \alpha\mathbf{U} + \beta\mathbf{V}
$$

Then $T(z\mathbf{N}) = \mathbf{0}$ for all $z$, so the line in the direction of $\mathbf{N}$ gets mapped to the origin, which means that this line is the kernel of $T$.

In short, if $\text{Im}(T)$ is a plane through the origin, then $\ker(T)$ is the line through the origin normal to this plane.